# How to connect to db using jndi and only through xml files not through InitialContext

Tags: java

Please guide me on this ?? As I have already worked on

```
     private void initializeDataSource() throws SystemException {
        // set up the parameters for the data source to be used by the
        // connection factory
        try {
             ctx  = new InitialContext();
            if (ctx == null)
                throw new SystemException("Unable to get Initial Context");

            this.dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:/dbname);

        } catch (NamingException ne) {
            throw new SystemException(ne);
        }
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Where is your XML config, and what error do you get, if any? Furthermore, the above won't compile, you are missing a `"` at the end of your connection string.

Comment: Hello, Actually we have been connecting to db using jndi name which is hard coded in the java class.But know, as client request is that , he wants to change the jndi names when ever he likes and that is through xml.

Comment: And what is your concrete programing problem with that? Where are you stuck on it? What error do you get, how have you gotten this started?

Comment: In the above code we would hard code the jndi name(dbname) and that jndi name is specified in the jboss server mysql-ds.xml and their to the particular jndi name the db is mapped. My question is how to connect to db using context path (jboss-web.xml) ???